# How to create the following effect in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an effect in `jquery`/ `javascript` so that the play button in the image grows to some size then shrinks back suddenly with a bouncy/pulsating effect.

[image: img1]

Comment: Have you looked through [the list of jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) to see if any look suitable, perhaps the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method (which allows you to animate a change in numeric CSS properties such as width and height)?

Comment: I'd use CSS for this! https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Thx a lot Vohuman kindly add this effect to the image button as i am facing difficulty in doing so that would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with CSS3 animations.

---

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="myButton">
     <a class="myButton">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcuEp.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS for growing and shrinkin object:**

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 100px;
   text-align: center;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes zoomout {
from { -webkit-transform: none; }
50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
to { -webkit-transform: none; }
}

@keyframes zoomout {
from { transform: none; }
50% { transform: scale(1.5); }
to { transform: none; }
}

.myButton:hover {
-webkit-animation: zoomout 1s;
animation: zoomout 1s;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvf5625v/)

---

**CSS for bounce effect before shrinking to original size:**

```
.container {
width: 100%;
padding: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomout {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.35, 1.35, 1.35);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.35, 1.35, 1.35);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.8, .8, .8);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomout {
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.35, 1.35, 1.35);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale3d(1.35, 1.35, 1.35);
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale3d(.8, .8, .8);
  }
}

.myButton:hover {
-webkit-animation: zoomout 1.5s;
animation: zoomout 1.5s;
}
```

[jsFiddle for bounce CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/r3dh4r7/xcchxb0e/)

---

You can tweak the scale and animation to your taste. :)

Comment: hi,Thx for the efforts mate! but it dosent seem to work if you could create a fiddle and provide link that would be simply great!

Comment: What browser and version of it are you using? Also look at your code would help. Meanwhile let me get you a fiddle.

Comment: Its not working with webkit variant too so kindly add a link to a working example like a fiddle.

Comment: i have a video of what exactly do i want but dont know how to share it if you need let me know

Comment: this is your code tried and didn't work kindly spot error if any

Comment: <style>
@-webkit-keyframes zoomout {
from { -webkit-transform: none; }
50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
to { -webkit-transform: none; }
}

@keyframes zoomout {
from { transform: none; }
50% { transform: scale(1.5); }
to { transform: none; }
}

.myButton:hover {
-webkit-animation: zoomout 1s;
animation: zoomout 1s;
}
</style>

Comment: <body>
<a class="myButton"><img src="play.png" alt="" /></a>
</body>

Comment: I believe providing a fiddle should solve my problem

Comment: thanks a lot mate it works perfect just o last thing when ut shrinks back to original size can it be a bit bouncy like shrinking and then growing to a very sort distance and the shrink

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfc39a3l4kye2y5/play.mp4?dl=0 . This is a video of what exactly i want if you could help that would be incredible!

Comment: I tried emulating what I saw in the video.. you tell me if it looks like it: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r3dh4r7/xcchxb0e/)

Comment: it is almost same just it lacks th bouncy effect when it shrinks back. You can go through the video again

Comment: Mate the bounce effect on shrink is still not there i mean there is a pulse effect when it shrinks as you could see in the video actually i want that effect and i am astuck there

Comment: Updated again with shrink/pulse/bounce hacks. Check the second fiddle. This is the closest I could come to emulating the effect in the video... I think.

Comment: I've also edited your question with the video link you provided as a comment for whoever stumbles upon this to understand you better. Well... it's being reviewed anyway.

Comment: Thx a lot for the sincere effeorts mate!